# node-serialport does not work with Electron

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port, node-gyp, electron

My task is to build a HTML5 desktop app, which works with serial port, because I have an arduino on the other side on COM-port.

I installed `electron-prebuilt` and `serialport` packages both (I specified them in `package.json`).
In my main web page I included `main.js`, and there I tried to require the `serialport` package, but I got the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module
>   'D:\Projects\arduino\HTMLPresentation\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport\v1.7.4\Release\node-v45-win32-x64\serialport.node'

I've read some QA topics about that problem (some abracadabras with `node-gyp`), but noting works for me: on both windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04. I don't know how to adopt serialport package for electron.

Comment: You are not the first one having problems with native modules. You just have to build it against electron headers!

Comment: How? All manuals that I saw are good only for previous versions.

Comment: Have you seen the [doc](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md)?

Comment: I saw it earlier, but this time you wrote me, I tried again. Nope, it doesn't work. Again it produces errors.

Comment: Say, have you set your `NODE_PATH` correctly?

Comment: `rainman@rainman:~$ echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript`

Comment: See? Your module path is not there :/ or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

My enviroment:

```
Vue.js: 2.6.10
Electron: 2.0.18
Node: 8.9.3
Platform: linux
```

If you are using Eletron with Vue.js you need to rebuild the serialport module doing something like this:

```
npm install electron-rebuild --save-dev
```

after this, you can add in your package.json > section "scripts", another line saying:

```
"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w serialport"
```

You can rebuild the module with terminal command

```
npm run rebuild
```

Now the serialport module should be imported and will work as expected. Goog luck!

Comment: I also noticed that electron-rebuild postinstall "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild.cmd" won't re-compile this package unless its under dependencies. In other words, it ignores devDependencies. Or at least it did not work for serialport when it was a dev dependency

Answer (score 3):

Use [Electron-Rebuild](https://github.com/electronjs/electron-rebuild): This executable rebuilds native io.js modules against the version of io.js that your Electron project is using. This allows you to use native io.js modules in Electron apps without your system version of io.js matching exactly.

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

# Every time you run "npm install", run this
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild

# On Windows if you have trouble, try:
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you would solve it

> Install windows build tools in your computer by running this in your powershell with administrator access

```
 npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

> or npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools

```
 setx PYTHON "%USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools/python27/python.exe"

 set PYTHON
```

> set PYTHON helps you check if its set up correctly.
>
> This is not enough install electron rebuild globally in your project files

```
 npm install -g electron-prebuilt  
 npm install --save serialport
```

> We have to rebuild serialport to work with electron. To do this, we need to >install electron-rebuild:

```
 npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

> The last step is to run electron-rebuild, once again, just in the root >directory of the app:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

> import and use in your electron-vue project

```
<script>     
  const sp = require('serialport')
  export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    methods: {},
    created () {
      sp.list(function (error, ports) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        } else {
          console.log(ports)
        }
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```